# Sharing scope between Directives - missing $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here are mine two directives. I basically want to share the scope between them. However with this I get an undefined `$http` error. I know I need to put `$http` somewhere, but where?

```
aresAnalytics.directive('market', function($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function ($scope, Data) {
            $scope.data = Data;
        },

        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function() {

                console.log("A1 " + attrs.market);

                scope.temp = attrs.market;

                $http.get('get_markets').success(function(markets) {
                    Data.markets =  markets;
                });

            })
        }
    }
});

aresAnalytics.directive('events', function($http) {
   return {
       restrict: 'E',

       controller: function ($scope) {
           scope = $scope;
       },


       link: function(scope, element) {

           element.bind('click', function() {
               console.log(scope.temp);
           });

       }
   }
});
```

HTML:

```
    <market ng-repeat="market in data.markets" market="{{ market }}">
        {{ market }}
    </market>
```

Also, I think the way I am doing this

```
 $http.get('get_markets').success(function(markets) {
        Data.markets =  markets;
});
```

is not correct, what can I replace with it.

And, should I use Isolate Scope '@' instead? How will that look like?

Thanks for reading this!

Comment: `aresAnalytics.directive('market', function($http) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to inject the `$http` service like so.

```
app.directive('something', function( $http ) { ... });
```

## [Angular Dependency Injection](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

To access attributes like that there are many ways, but this is a simple way.

change html to

```
  <market ng-repeat="market in data.markets" market="market">
        {{ market }}
  </market>
```

Require parse like this

```
app.directive('something', function( $http, $parse ) { ... });
```

And get your attribute like so

```
scope.temp = $parse(attrs.market)(scope);
```

This way you're getting it directly from the scope while the other way, angular hasn't rendered the attribute yet.

Comment: console.log(scope.temp) will just say "undefined".

Comment: What's that got to do with `$http`

Comment: I am setting scope.temp = attrs.market in top, shouldn't it work?

Comment: I'm guessing in your html you have `market="{{something}}"` right?

Comment: Answer Updated, Common Problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your dependency injection. Try this:

```
aresAnalytics.directive('market', ['$http', function($http) {
    // (you code)
}]);
```

or if you don't use code minifiers/uglifiers:

```
aresAnalytics.directive('market', function($http) {
    // (you code)
});
```

Comment: I tried this, I updated the code and get undefined with that. I'm sure I'm making a silly error somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but I simply had to append a `$parent` to my scope to always use the parent scope. (like use `scope.$parent` instead of `scope`).

REF: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes